# Identifying the 3rd row in a MySQL while loop

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm doing is for every 3rd outputted MySQL database row, I'll run a custom function that outputs differently. How would I identify every 3rd row?

Comment: Is this purely for styling purpose (that could be achieved by adding a class in the HTML code) or do you need a different treatment in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will be kinda repeating the others , but :

```
$i = 1;
while ( $data = $pdo_statement->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) )
{
    if ( $i++ % 3 === 0 )
    {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Very simple. You can do something like this:

```
$i = 1;
while ( $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
   if ($i % 3 == 0)
   {
      // call other function
   }
   $i++;
}
```

Please, note the use of the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby Glad to help you. Don't forget to accept answers also for your past questions.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby Just as you have done for the teresko question. Anyway you can find more info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

This will call the specific function every 3rd row

```
$cpt = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 if($cpt % 3 == 0){
  do_something_custom();
 }
 $cpt++;
}
```